# Manually updating a foreign key.

Tags: android, realm

I am pretty much aware of the absence of foreign keys in Realm. But I encountered this issue. I receive data in a normalised way and I have to figure out how to properly persist the relations.

Example:

```
class User{
  private int id;
  private Email email;
}

class Email{
  private int id;
  private String address;
}
```

And I receive something like:

```
{user={id:1, emailId:1}}
```

How can I store this type of data in my existing realm object  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to parse the JSON yourself to setup the links. From your description it isn't clear if you User and Email is already in Realm, but if that is the case I would do something like this:

```
class User{
  @PrimaryKey
  private int id;
  private Email email;
}

class Email{
  @PrimaryKey
  private int id;
  private String address;
}


JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{id:1, emailId:1}");

realm.beginTransaction();
User user = realm.where(User.class).equalTo("id", json.getInt("id")).findFirst();
Email email = realm.where(Email.class).equalTo("id", json.getInt("emailId")).findFirst();
user.setEmail(email);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did failed to explain that I do not have any guarantee that either object is in the Realm already. So I could use the answer you provided only in the case I would certainly know the objects are already in the Realm.

Comment: Depending on how your JSON is organised you can still use my answer if you use Realm.createOrUpdateFromJson() to insert your User/Email objects, and then run the above.